# How to create alias for action in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, configuration, struts2

Both of these files are having same validation rules.How to used same xml for mupltiple Actions?

```
Action1-validation.xml
Action2-validation.xml
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="Action1" class="test.Action1"/>
<action name="Action2" class="test.Action2"/>
```

Now how to use the same validation file based on the Action alias name for both Actions? How to create alias name for an Action ?

---

```
Action1
{
  String name;
  Date dob;
  int age;
}
Action2
{
  String name;
  Date dob;
  int age;
}
```

what is the meaning of ActionAliasName and How to create that ?,which is mentioned from below line.

```
The validation.xml format is either <ActionClassName>-validation.xml or <ActionClassName>-<ActionAliasName>-validation.xml.
```

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking. Describe step-by-step your problem.

Comment: You can use action config to define an alias, what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for confusion made by me.Please check the update Question.And what you mean by config.?

Comment: @RomanC, said,he implement a Action1 xml validation already.now he wants to rewrite same(Action1) validation in Action2 class.and his mission without implement a coding of Action2.can we use Action1 methods validations?through using Alias?

Comment: @hari To use validations you should provide configuration files for validation rules. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the same validation file for both action classes because they have the same properties. You should read [Defining Validation Rules](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html#defining-validation-rules) and choose option 3. Create a base action class that has the same property set for both action classes and create `*-validation.xml` for this.

Actions are mapped to the methods by name in the action configuration. This name might differ from the method name, that's why it's called an action alias.

You might also been interested [How Validators of an Action are Found](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html#how-validators-of-an-action-are-found) that will compliment said above.

Another option is to use one class for actions that are mapped to different methods and use the same per action class validation.